# MongoDB $push aggregaton won't keep the right order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried to make a $group aggregation with MongoDB, like the following example:

```
"$group": {
            "_id": "$test_id",
            "feeling": {
                "$push": "$feeling"
            },
            "reference_id": {
                "$push": "$_id"
            },
            "training_start": {
                "$push": "$training_start"
            },
            "training_duration": {
                "$push": "$duration_ms"
            }
        }
```

The aggregation works fine, but the created arrays are sorted different. That means, if I check the result of the aggregation by looking at **reference_id[x]** and **training_start[x]** then the value of **training_start** in the source collection is not equal to **training_start[x]**.

Maybe an example shows my problem more precisely:

One document after the **$group** aggregation:

```
{
  _id: "string_1",
  reference_id: [1, 2, 3],
  training_start: [01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00] (date times)
}
```

Documents from source collection:

```
{
  _id:1,
  training_start: 01:00:00,
  test_id: "string_1"
},
{
  _id:2,
  training_start: 03:00:00,
  test_id: "string_1"
},
{
  _id:3,
  training_start: 02:00:00,
  test_id: "string_1"
}
```

The first elements in these arrays are always in the right order. So I checked if each grouped field has the same number of entries by using the code below. And the annoying result is, that the amount of entries in each array is equal. So there is no shift in the arrays caused by missing values.

```
"$group": {
            "_id": "$test_id",
            "sum": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                          "$lte": [
                              "$training_start", null
                            ]
                        },
                        "then": 0,
                        "else": 1
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does anybody know, if there is an other way to create arrays (already tried **$addToSet**) which keep the order, the elements where pushed in? Or am I the problem?

Greetings Max

Comment: " no shift in the arrays caused by missing values." - Does this mean you don't have a field but you expect $push to add empty value?

Comment: @Gibbs:
All fields that I want to add to my arrays are existing. I only checked if all arrays have the same size, and they all have the same size. It was a, let's say sanity check, if the data in all grouped documents are available.